# Conseguir el valor de un campo en Firebase en Android Studio

Tags: android, base-de-datos, firebase

Estoy haciendo una app donde al ingresar en un `EditText` un valor, sí este concuerda con alguno de la base de datos en **Firebase** mostrara en un `TextView` lo que dice el valor de ese campo.

A continuación les muestro una foto de como esta estructurada la base de datos:
[image: Estructura de la Base de datos en Firebase]

Para que entiendan mejor me refiero a que en el `EditText` ingresare un numero y si este concuerda con alguno de los números de la base de datos me mostrara el **"Texto n"** correspondiente.

Y este es el código

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private TextView mEstado;
private Button B_buscar;
private EditText E_buscar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("no_orden");

    mEstado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.estado);
    B_buscar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.B_buscar);
    E_buscar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.E_buscar);

    B_buscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String buscar = E_buscar.getText().toString().trim();
            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String estado = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    if (estado.equals(dataSnapshot.child(buscar))) {
                        //Haz algo
                        mEstado.setText("El estado de la orden #" + buscar + " es: " + estado);
                        //Haz otra cosa
                    }else {
                        if (buscar.equals("")){
                            mEstado.setText("Ingrese un numero de orden valido.");
                        }else {
                            mEstado.setText("La orden #" + buscar + " no existe.");
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}}
```

**El problema que tengo** es que siempre que ingreso un numero me dice que ese valor no existe, es decir, se pasa a la ultima sentencia else. Creo que no esta haciendo la comparación con los datos de la DB.
Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Al ser todos hijos de `no_orden`  tendrías que recorrerlos todos con un iterator e ir comparando. Ejemplo: `@Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               
                DataSnapshot firstChild = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
if (firstChild.getValue().equals(buscar)){ //Iguales }else{ //Diferentes}
            }`

Comment: Oh entiendo si funciona pero sabes si hay alguna manera de hacerlo por el key? osea si el key == 1 que me muestre lo que contiene su "value"?

Comment: Agregas la condición al if: `if (firstChild.getValue().equals(buscar) && !firstChild.getKey().equals("1")){`... Aunque no sé si sea mejor usar una query que busque el valor específico... así te evitas tener que traer todos los valores e iterar sobre ellos.

Comment: Gracias si me funciono :)
El unico problema que me falta es que solo me lee la primer iteracion osea si ingreso "2" para que me devuelva el valor de ese campo no lo hace.

Answer (score 1):

Tu método `onDataChange` debería quedar más o menos así.

- Los datos son leídos en un bucle `for`.
- Esta línea: `ds.getValue().equals(buscar) && !ds.getKey().equals("1")` evalúa si el valor de cada clave es igual al valor de `buscar` y al mismo tiempo evalúa que la clave no sea igual a `1`.

  ```
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  if (ds.getValue().equals(buscar) && !ds.getKey().equals("1")){

                      //Iguales

                      }else{

                          //No iguales

                      }
              }
          }
  ```